# limit clause in codeingiter does't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

my limit in below code doesn't work. query fetch all records :

```
    $this->db->select('users.id as user_id');
    $this->db->select('users.username');
    $this->db->select('traction_details.title');
    $this->db->select('traction_details.tr_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.buy_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.coupon_code');
    $this->db->select('tractions.coupon_property_id');
    $this->db->select('tractions.expired');


    $this->db->from('tractions');


    $this->db->join('traction_details' , 'traction_details.tr_id = tractions.id');
    $this->db->join('users' , 'tractions.user_id = users.id');
    $this->db->join('coupon_cats' , 'tractions.coupon_parent = coupon_cats.coupon_id');
    $this->db->where('coupon_cats.cat_id =' , '13');
    $this->db->where('tractions.succ =' , '1');

    $this->db->group_by('tractions.buy_id');
    $this->db->order_by('traction_details.tr_id', 'desc');

    $this->db->limit(0, 10);


    $result = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in [limit()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) lets you set a result offset,so you need to reverse the limit and offset as,

```
..
$this->db->limit(0, 10);
..
```

to

```
..
$this->db->limit(10, 0);
..
```